# Can change the field type after creating the table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having an minor problem using sql server 2008. When I go for create an database table, after that, i can't change the field type at all(showing an permission error). I tried to set an field as primary key after the table created. I think, i will have to change some settings somewhere. But, don't know where. Please help.

Regards

Comment: If it's a permission issue you probably need to the `alter table` privilege on the schema in question.

Comment: Can you please explain details steps plz?

Comment: What actual, specific, error message do you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just created the table I'm going to assume it's unlikely to be a permissions error. You probably need to turn this option off in Management Studio.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes its happening on new;y created tables. Thank for the info.